# PHP code is getting, just not getting the ID like it was, so it's not updating correctly

Tags: php, mysqli, show

I've rewritten the code to break up as much PHP and html as possible, Honestly I thin it looks ugly, but people here seem to think it is good practise.

In any case, the drop down menus are still in all PHP because I couldn't figure out how to write it in html.

In any case if anyone can do that for me great, but here is my real problem now.  Everything shows... I just can't post, and I can't figure out why.  Here is the code, and the errors:

```
<?php
require_once('tb/connectvars.php');
echo '<div id="postwrap">';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PDI NCMR - Edit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tb/postie.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="../images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
;   
// Enter data into the database
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['id']));
    $ab = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comp']));
    $ncmrid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrid']));
    $rma = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rma']));
    $jno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['jno']));
    $fdt = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fdt']));
    $cof = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cof']));
    $fab1= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab1']));
    $fab2= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab2']));
    $fab3= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab3']));
    $non= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['non']));
    $dis= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['dis']));
    $comm= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comm']));
    $caad= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['caad']));
    $po= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['po']));
    $pod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']))));
    $dri = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']))));

    $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = '$id'";

// echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";

// and at least use a basic mechanism to trap possibles errors
       mysqli_query($dbc, $query)  or die('Query Error : ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

// Clear the data to clear the form
    $id = "";
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $comp = "";
    $ncmrid = "";
    $rma = "";
    $jno = "";
    $fdt = "";
    $cof = "";
    $fab1= "";
    $fab2= "";
    $fab3= "";
    $non= "";
    $dis= "";
    $comm= "";
    $caad= "";
    $po= "";
    $pod = "";
    $dri = "";

// Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>If you wish to edit more NCMRs, please <a href="list.php">go to the admin page!</a></p>';

            mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

  else {    

// Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Grab the profile data from the database
 if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
  }
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    echo'<div id="title"><h3 id="NCMR2">Non-Conforming Materials Report (NCMR:&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $row['rma'] . ')</h3></div>';

    if (empty($row['ab'])) $row['ab'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['date'])) $row['date'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['part'])) $row['part'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['rev'])) $row['rev'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";
    if (empty($row['ncmrqty'])) $row['ncmrqty'] = "Empty";
    if (empty($row['comp'])) $row['comp'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['ncmrid'])) $row['ncmrid'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['rma'])) $row['rma'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['jno'])) $row['jno'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['non'])) $row['non'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['dis'])) $row['dis'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['comm'])) $row['comm'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['caad'])) $row['caad'] == "Empty";
    if (empty($row['po'])) $row['po'] =="Empty";
    if (empty($row['pod'])) $row['pod'] =="Empty";
    if (empty($row['dir'])) $row['dri'] =="Empty";

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="box1">
            <div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="<?php echo $row['ab']?>" /></div>
            <div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $row['date']?>" /></div>
            <div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="<?php echo $row['part']?>" /></div>
            <div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="<?php echo $row['rev']?>" /></div>
            <div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22" value=><?php echo $row['partdesc']?></textarea></div>
            <div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="<?php echo $row['ncmrqty']?>"/></div>    
        </div>

        <div id="box2">
            <div id="comp"><span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="comp" value="<?php echo $row['comp']?>" /></div>
            <div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="<?php echo $row['ncmrid']?>" /></div>
            <div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="<?php echo $row['rma']?>" /></div>
            <div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="<?php echo $row['jno']?>" /></div>
        </div>

        <div id="box3">
            <h2>Failure</h2>
                <div id="cof"><span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="cof" size="15" value="<?php echo $row['cof']?>" /></div>
                <div id="fdt"><span class="b">Failure Due To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="fdt" size="15" value="<?php echo $row['fdt']?>" /></div>
        </div>
<?php
        echo '<div id="box4">';
            echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']=="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['userid']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab1"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
}

if ($row['fab2']=="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab2'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['userid']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab2"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab2"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab2'] . '" /></div>';
}
if ($row['fab3']=="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab3">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab3'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['userid']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab3"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab3"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab3'] . '" /></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
        <div id="box5">
            <div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105" value=><?php echo $row['non']?></textarea></div>
            <div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105" value=><?php echo $row['dis']?></textarea></div>
            <div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105" value=><?php echo $row['comm']?></textarea></div>
            <div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105" value=><?php echo $row['caad']?></textarea></div>
        </div>

        <div id="podr">
        <div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="<?php echo $row['po']?>" /></div>
        <div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="<?php echo $row['pod']?>" /></div>
        <div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value="<?php echo $row['dri']?>" /></div>
        </div>
            <div id="button2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" /></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<?php
        }
    }


echo '</div>';
?>
```

The error is this:

> Query is : UPDATE ncmr SET ab = 'Matt Ridge', date = '2012-01-09', part = 'K17212191', rev = '01' , partdesc = '' , ncmrqty = '2' , comp = 'Charles River Labs' , ncmrid = '1243' , rma = 'Empty' , jno = 'Empty' , fdt = 'Third Party' , cof = 'Materials' , fab1 = 'Andy Kahl' , fab2 = 'Anthony Ayoub' , fab3 = fab3' , non = '' , dis = '' , comm = '' , caad = '' , po = '1' , pod = '2011-01-01' , dri = '2011-01-03' WHERE id = ''
>
> Query Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' , non = '' , dis = '' , comm = '' , caad = '' , po = '1' , pod = '2011-01-01' ' at line 1

It is not pulling the ID again, I thought I fixed this with the code before, but it seems not. If anyone can give me a bit of help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, you should fix first.

For example don't use = for comparison in if-statements like

```
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
```

The condition will always evaluate to true because you are doing an assignment instead of a comparison. correct way:

```
if ($row['fab3'] == "--None--")
```

In the same block you used the variable $row again for a different purpose:

```
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
{
    // [...]
    // assigning $row with something different
    // use a different variable like $row2 here
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    // [...]
}
// $row from now on contains the last tuple you fetched inside the above while-loop
```

Let us know if this fixes your problem.

A unrelated suggestion: Don't mix php and html in one file. use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

**Edit1**

i suggest to look at the variable $query from this block.

```
  if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
  }
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
```

var_dump($query); and execute this query in phpmyadmin. if the query results the desired rows, var_dump the variable $row right after the mysqli_fetch_array. if it also contains the desired rows just follow the code and var_dump until you find a line after which it got corrupted.

Comment: I did the == as you suggested, and it still isn't working... any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, on your side note, I was taught to mix php and html together, I am attempting to unlearn that way... it's not as easy as I am hoping, but till i get there I am forced to keep my old stuff the way it is now... I will be breaking this code up later to fix the issue, but it is going to take time...

Comment: have you considered the 2nd issue where you reused your variable $row? i think this might be your problem. i edited my answer with another suggestion. hope that helps. if not could you please provide the table schematics and the initialisation in connectvars.php, if there are any (for instance for $id) so that i can run this myself?

Comment: i got Notice: "Undefined variable: id in /NCMR2/@dm!n/edit.php on line 46" and a failed query. and after changing the = to ==, inserting a random tuple with non = "TEST" and calling edit.php?id=1 i got a text box containing TEST for Nonconformity. after inserting "--None--" into fab3, i got Empty again because $row gets overwritten. please read my answer again and correct the first 2 issues. then it will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7985/discussion-between-matt-ridge-and-basti)